# Hazelcast: There is no suitable de-serializer for type 1453

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security, hazelcast

I am trying to add Hazelcast as a session manager with a spring boot project.
I created a Hazelcast cluster in docker and Hazelcast client using Java like the code below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableHazelcastHttpSession
public class SessionConfiguration {

    private final String SESSIONS_MAP_NAME = "session-map";

    @Bean
    @SpringSessionHazelcastInstance
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.setClusterName("dev");
        clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("192.168.192.5:5701").setSmartRouting(false);

        SerializerConfig serializerConfig = new SerializerConfig();
        serializerConfig.setImplementation(new HazelcastSessionSerializer()).setTypeClass(MapSession.class);
        clientConfig.getSerializationConfig().addSerializerConfig(serializerConfig);


        clientConfig.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig()
                .setEnabled(true)
                .addClass(Session.class)
                .addClass(MapSession.class)
                .addClass(Hazelcast4SessionUpdateEntryProcessor.class);

        return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRepositoryCustomizer<Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository> customize() {
        return (sessionRepository) -> {
            sessionRepository.setFlushMode(FlushMode.IMMEDIATE);
            sessionRepository.setSaveMode(SaveMode.ALWAYS);
            sessionRepository.setSessionMapName(SESSIONS_MAP_NAME);
            sessionRepository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(900);
        };
    }
}
```

I can connect to the cluster and see the map created using Hazelcast mancenter, but when I try to connect to the application I have this exception.

```
error:There is no suitable de-serializer for type 1453. This exception is likely caused by differences in the serialization configuration between members or between clients and members.
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503294200Z com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: There is no suitable de-serializer for type 1453. This exception is likely caused by differences in the serialization configuration between members or between clients and members.
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503373800Z          at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.newHazelcastSerializationException(AbstractSerializationService.java:319) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503406600Z          at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:259) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503454200Z          at com.hazelcast.query.impl.CachedQueryEntry.getValue(CachedQueryEntry.java:116) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503473000Z          at org.springframework.session.hazelcast.Hazelcast4SessionUpdateEntryProcessor.process(Hazelcast4SessionUpdateEntryProcessor.java:46) ~[spring-session-hazelcast-2.6.1.jar!/:2.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503534900Z          at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperator.process(EntryOperator.java:338) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503556600Z          at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperator.operateOnKeyValueInternal(EntryOperator.java:193) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503593400Z          at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperator.operateOnKey(EntryOperator.java:176) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503611200Z          at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperation.call(EntryOperation.java:193) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503645700Z          at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:273) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503663400Z          at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:248) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503700100Z          at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:471) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503719600Z          at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:197) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503760100Z          at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:137) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503778200Z          at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.executeRun(OperationThread.java:123) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503814300Z          at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503832300Z          at ------ submitted from ------.() ~[?:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503867900Z          at com.hazelcast.internal.util.ExceptionUtil.cloneExceptionWithFixedAsyncStackTrace(ExceptionUtil.java:336) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503907000Z          at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.returnOrThrowWithGetConventions(InvocationFuture.java:112) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503958400Z          at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:95) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.503977600Z          at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:40) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504049500Z          at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:617) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504072100Z          at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.ClientProxy.invokeOnPartition(ClientProxy.java:188) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504121800Z          at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:182) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504140400Z          at com.hazelcast.client.impl.proxy.ClientMapProxy.executeOnKeyInternal(ClientMapProxy.java:1368) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504175600Z          at com.hazelcast.client.impl.proxy.ClientMapProxy.executeOnKey(ClientMapProxy.java:1360) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar!/:5.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504193000Z          at org.springframework.session.hazelcast.Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.save(Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.java:267) ~[spring-session-hazelcast-2.6.1.jar!/:2.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504229100Z          at org.springframework.session.hazelcast.Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository$HazelcastSession.flushImmediateIfNecessary(Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.java:472) ~[spring-session-hazelcast-2.6.1.jar!/:2.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504248000Z          at org.springframework.session.hazelcast.Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository$HazelcastSession.setLastAccessedTime(Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.java:377) ~[spring-session-hazelcast-2.6.1.jar!/:2.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504289000Z          at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:324) ~[spring-session-core-2.6.1.jar!/:2.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504307000Z          at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:193) ~[spring-session-core-2.6.1.jar!/:2.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504343400Z          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:244) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504360800Z          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:244) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504399200Z          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:244) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504417700Z          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:244) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504453200Z          at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.SessionMap.setAttribute(SessionMap.java:56) ~[myfaces-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504471000Z          at org.apache.myfaces.util.AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.put(AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.java:109) ~[myfaces-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504523000Z          at org.apache.myfaces.util.AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.put(AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.java:38) ~[myfaces-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504542600Z          at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.getResponseEncoding(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2403) ~[myfaces-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504580600Z          at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2303) ~[myfaces-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504599300Z          at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1867) ~[myfaces-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504644600Z          at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:315) ~[myfaces-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504662900Z          at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:73) ~[myfaces-api-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504701800Z          at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:117) ~[myfaces-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504719800Z          at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:266) [myfaces-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504754600Z          at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:206) [myfaces-api-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504772200Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504806700Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504824200Z          at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504859000Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504876700Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504944800Z          at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.504964100Z          at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.505004600Z          at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.505023200Z          at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.505059400Z          at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506154800Z          at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506223700Z          at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506240900Z          at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506249200Z          at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506272200Z          at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506280300Z          at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506287200Z          at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506294400Z          at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506302000Z          at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506308900Z          at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506315900Z          at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506322800Z          at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506329900Z          at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506339200Z          at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506346400Z          at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506353500Z          at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506360500Z          at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506367500Z          at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506374200Z          at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506380700Z          at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506386400Z          at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506392300Z          at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506404700Z          at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506411100Z          at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506417100Z          at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506423600Z          at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506430700Z          at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506438500Z          at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506444600Z          at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) [spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506450800Z          at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506456800Z          at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506462900Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506468800Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506475100Z          at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506481200Z          at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506487900Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506494500Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506500100Z          at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506522400Z          at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506532300Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506540300Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506546400Z          at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:142) [spring-session-core-2.6.1.jar!/:2.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506561000Z          at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82) [spring-session-core-2.6.1.jar!/:2.6.1]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506567300Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506573600Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506579500Z          at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506585000Z          at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506591100Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506597300Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506603800Z          at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506610900Z          at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506617100Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506624100Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506630800Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506637400Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506644100Z          at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506650500Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506657900Z          at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506664500Z          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506670900Z          at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506677300Z          at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506683500Z          at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506703600Z          at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506711600Z          at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506718200Z          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506724900Z          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506731300Z          at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506737800Z          at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506744200Z          at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
2022-03-21T10:48:14.506750500Z          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
```

Any idea please ?

When I remove the `SerializerConfig`, I have another exception related to `MapSession` serialization.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I came across the same issue.

Comment: Seems that the custom serializer does not work when using hazelcast client-server topology.
Try removing the serializerConfig.